# ERROR 404 con un FORM POST pasando objeto MVC SPRING

Tags: mvc, spring, jsp, post

espero que me puedan ayudar, desde el index de mi proyecto el usuario va al boton "agregar vuelo" que usar el primer metodo que especifico en el controlador, ya desde esta vista, el usuario introduce datos del vuelo, este formulario esta con post y lo que quiero es enviar el vuelo en si y al enviarlo al controlador por el metodo post me salta el error -> Estado HTTP 400 – Bad Request El requerimiento enviado por el cliente era sintácticamente incorrecto. Les dejo el codigo. Gracias!

VISTA registroDeVuelo.jsp

```
        <form:form action="procesoCrearVuelo" method="POST" modelAttribute="vuelo">

            <label for="fechaDeDespegue">Fecha y hora de Despegue:</label>
            <form:input path="fechaDeDespegue" type="datetime-local"
                id="fechaDeDespegue" name="fechaDeDespegue" />
                
            <label for="fechaDeArribo">Fecha y hora de Arribo:</label>
            <form:input path="fechaDeArribo" type="datetime-local"
                id="fechaDeArribo" name="fechaDeArribo" />
                
            <div class="seleccionAeropuertoOrigen">
                <label for="aeropuertoOrigen">Origen:</label>
                <form:select path="origenAeropuerto" class="custom-select"
                    name="origenAeropuerto">
                    <c:forEach items="${aeropuertos}" var="aeropuerto">
                        <form:option value="${aeropuerto}">${aeropuerto.id_aeropuerto}
                            (${aeropuerto.nombre})</form:option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </form:select>
            </div>

            <div class="seleccionAeropuertoDestino">
                <label for="destinoAeropuerto">Destino:</label>
                <form:select path="destinoAeropuerto" class="custom-select"
                    name="destinoAeropuerto">
                    <c:forEach items="${aeropuertos}" var="aeropuerto">
                        <option value="${aeropuerto}" selected>${aeropuerto.id_aeropuerto}
                            (${aeropuerto.nombre})</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </form:select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="aeronaveDeVuelo">Aeronave del vuelo:</label>
                <form:select path="aeronaveDeVuelo" class="custom-select"
                    name="aeronaveDeVuelo">
                    <c:forEach items="${aeronaves}" var="aeronave">
                        <option value="${aeronave}" selected>${aeronave.nombre}-
                            ${aeronave.matricula}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </form:select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Sumar
                    vuelo</button>
            </div>
        </form:form>
```

Controlador

```
**ESTE METODO LLEVA A LA VISTA PARA INGRESAR EL VUELO, POR ESO ESTA EL OBJETO VACIO**
@RequestMapping("/direccionCrearVuelo")
    public ModelAndView irASumarNuevoVuelo() {

        Set<Aeropuerto> aeropuertos = servicioAeropuerto.obtenerAeropuertos();
        Set<Aeronave> aeronaves = servicioAeronave.obtenerAeronaves();
        Vuelo vuelo = new Vuelo();
        ModelMap modelo = new ModelMap();
        modelo.put("aeropuertos", aeropuertos);
        modelo.put("aeronaves", aeronaves);
        modelo.put("vuelo", vuelo);
        

        return new ModelAndView("registroDeVuelo", modelo);
    }

**ESTE METODO ES EL QUE RECIBE EL FORMULARIO**
    @RequestMapping(path="procesoCrearVuelo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView procesoCrearVuelo(@ModelAttribute("vuelo") Vuelo vuelo) {
        

        ModelMap modelo = new ModelMap();
        modelo.put("vuelo", vuelo);
        
        Long instanciado = servicioVuelo.persistirVuelo(vuelo);
        
        return new ModelAndView("registroDeVuelo", modelo);
    }
```

MODEL VUELO

```
@Entity
public class Vuelo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long nro_vuelo;
    @ManyToOne
    private Aeropuerto origenAeropuerto;
    @ManyToOne
    private Aeropuerto destinoAeropuerto;
    @ManyToOne
    private Aeronave aeronaveDeVuelo;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") 
    private LocalDateTime fechaDeDespegue;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime fechaDeArribo;
    
    private Double horasDiurnas;
    private Double horasNocturnas;

    private Estacion estacion;

    public Vuelo() {
    }
```

Tengo q agregar texto jejejejeeje

Comment: Agregale el "/"  al path para que quede: `/procesoCrearVuelo`  y al action: `ction="/procesoCrearVuelo" `

Comment: Lo hice y me devuelve-: El recurso requerido [/procesoCrearVuelo] no se encuentra disponible - probe agregandole la barra solo en el controlador y no en la vista y tampoco anda, me tira el primer error que puse en el titulo de la pregunta

Comment: Prueba esto: define  una variable con el valor del url: `<c:url var="procesarCrearVuelo_url" value="/procesoCrearVuelo"/>` y luego utiliza esta variable en el action: `action="${procesarCrearVuelo}"`. En el controlador le agregas el `/`

Comment: Me funciona pero no me agrega a la base el vuelo, por que puede ser? tengo el metodo servicioVuelo.persistirVuelo(vuelo); que lleva a  Override
 public Long persistirVuelo(Vuelo vuelo) {
  return repositorioVuelo.persistirVuelo(vuelo);
 } y despues a   @Override
 public Long persistirVuelo(Vuelo vuelo) {
  return (Long) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(vuelo);
 }

Comment: ¿Te da algún error?

Comment: no, no hace nada, pero no me tira error por suerte

Comment: Hubiera preferido que  tire error porque nos una idea de por donde puede ser. ¿Puedes ver si tu clase `Vuelo` llega con datos correctos? Lo que no me cuadra es por qué el `save` no da error si hubiera algo raro. Salvo que lo estes controlando el error.

Comment: Me parece pueden ser  tus relaciones `ManyToOne`

Comment: es que tiene logica porque un aeropuerto tiene muchos vuelos pero un vuelo tiene un aeropuerto

Comment: Quizá solo te hace falta marcar la transacción antes y despues del `save` (teniendo en cuenta que no hay errores, entonces, supongamos que hace falta el commit:  `Transaction tx=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();`  `long result = (Long) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(vuelo);` `tx.commit();`  `return result;`

Comment: Utiliza mejor: `Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` y utilizas ~ `session`. Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction(); long result = (Long) session.save(vuelo); tx.commit(); return result;